# Headphones stopped working in Windows (working fine in other OS)

Tags: windows, audio, headphones

All of a sudden, my headphones stopped working with windows 8 in my laptop. Sound plays fine through built in speakers. Its not a problem with the hardware, because, I dual boot ubuntu and sound plays fine in Ubuntu.

These are the things I have tried:
- Restarting and blah blah. Restarted 20 times i think, alternating windows and ubuntu.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Realtek drivers.
- Troubleshooting from control panel (it says "coudnt identify problem")

What might be the problem?

Comment: Its not a mic, its a headphone with speakers only!!! I dont think the model matters, because it it working in ubuntu but not in windows. And it was working in windows too, before yesterday.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer for you. If you gave more details of your problem you may be able to get more assistance.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/772588/headphone-playback-not-working/784406#784406

Answer (score 1):

Some setting may be muting the headphones or the headphones volume has been set to 0. Have a look in the device settings itself and check the capture settings. Learn your way around it if you haven't already done so. I believe it would be in Winkey-x -> 'Hardware and Sound'.