# Headphone playback not working

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers

I am using an Acer S7-191 with Windows 8.1, I had the system reinstalled with the same Windows version after an windows update crashed the system.

The problem is I cannot plug headphone to playback. In playback devices, there are only Speaker and Digital Audio HDMI even after I chose to display all disconnected and disabled device.

Here are what I have tried:

- Install all recommended driver on Acer's website
- Install and reinstall Realtek's software and driver
- Update driver in device manager
- Disable front panel jack detection in Realtek software provided by Acer (after that no "2nd Output" tab appeared)
- Check if there is any device unrecognized or with warning mark, none found
- Change a headphone to try the connector
- Use Realtek official universal software instead of Acer's

The jack is a input/output hybrid one, standard 3.5mm, so are the headphones I tried (one is a phone/mic mix one, another is a playback only one).

I am running out of solutions, anything else I can try?

Don't want to get to Acer maintenance, they can only let me ship my unit back to Texas!

**EDIT**

I guess I have tried everything I could software-wise. At last I decided to sent the unit back in for repair, came out fine with a hardware repair.

Thanks YatharthROCK for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my sporadic issues with Realtek on an ASUS laptop running Windows 8.1:

1. Finish any pending Windows Updates (optional);
2. Uninstall the Realtek software from "Programs and Features";
3. Confirm that the Realtek sound controller is gone from Device Manager (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> -> <kbd>M</kbd>);
4. Reboot to let the Windows stock drivers take control;
5. ???
6. Profit!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I did this to allow Windows driver to take control just after I uninstall the driver and before reinstall realtek driver, but nothing happens.

Comment: @LingyuanHe *shrugs* Do you see the in Sound Playback?

Comment: Just saw your edit to your question; you should create a answer saying mentioning how you fixed your problem (although how exactly can you be sure that they didn't just install some other driver at the repair unit?) and accept it (and possibly upvote this answer if you found it useful/relevant).